# jQuery and checkboxes, i can't see the changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

I have many checkboxes in a ASP item repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpPostes" runat="server" DataSource="<%# this.ItemsPostesBudgetaires %>">
```

Somewhere within the repeater, a checkBox described as :

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Class="chk" ID="chkPieceJust" Text="Recues" Visible="<%#  Mode.HasFlag(ModeType._BoutonsApprobation)  %>" Enabled="<%# CheckBoxDispo() %>" Checked="<%# CheckBoxChecked(Container.DataItem as Transaction) %>" />
```

At the end of all that, a button that is suppose to turn every checkBoxes to true :

```
<input id="chkAllPieceJust" type="button" value="Toutes Pièces Justificatives Recues" onclick="CTCC.Transactions.PieceRecuClick(this);" />
```

And finally here's my jQuery function :

```
CTCC.Transactions.PieceRecuClick = function (source) {

$('.chk').attr('checked', true);

}
```

What happens after I click the button is that kind of html output :

```
<span class="chk" checked="checked"><input ... blablabla
```

but nothing happens, checkboxes are not checked at all...

I can't figure what else do I need...

Comment: always use `.prop()` to set the `checked` property. See the section **Attributes vs. Properties** in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: Considering that documentation, attr is completely useless to me now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Checkbox` control's `CssClass` property actually applies the class to a `span` element that wraps the checkbox itself.  You can either apply the class directly to the checkbox element by assigning it in the codebehind like this:

```
MyCheckBox.InputAttributes["class"] = "chk";
```

Or modify your jquery to look for the input child element of the `.chk` element, like this

```
$(".chk input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: A perfect complet answer, and very well explained, I have nothing else too say, it worked.